# Maven dependency from nowhere

Tags: maven, struts2, dojo, dependencies

I'm updating the struts2 dependencies in our maven project. I'm getting this exception when the server starts up:

```
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary class:org.apache.struts2.dojo.views.DojoTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/I:/Trabajo/sts-bundle/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Atenea3/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:28:-1
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:271)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/views/TagLibrary
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2267)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1244)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:168)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:244)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
... 50 more
```

The weird thing is that I don't have a dependecy for struts2-dojo and I also don't see it in the eclipse dependecy hierarchy:

[image]

Also, if I add the latest version of the dependency manually I get both jars in the project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

If I delete the older version manually from the file system I don't get the exception on startup. Any idea where this jar is coming from??

Here's the POM:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/build/classes</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>utf8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:7980/manager</url>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-classes/cobertura</directory>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                </resource>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfreechart</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gnujaxp</groupId>
        <artifactId>gnujaxp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gnujaxp-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
        <version>20041228.180559</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
        <artifactId>doxia</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-findbugs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5M3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    hibernate-commons-annotations
                </artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.java.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.01</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/plugin.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>struts2.fullhibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>fullhibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.GA</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA-parche1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wss4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alfresco</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.b</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-3.4.b.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alfresco</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-web-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.b</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-web-client-3.4.b.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alfresco</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-web-service-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.b</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-web-service-client-3.4.b.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>20040218.194635</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.artofsolving</groupId>
        <artifactId>jodconverter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jodreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jodreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-parser-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-awt-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-awt-util-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-bridge-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-css</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-css-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-dom-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-ext-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-gui-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-gui-util-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-gvt-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-script</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-script-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-util-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-xml</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/batik-xml-1.6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsf</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libdocbundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfonts</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libformat</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libloader</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>librepository</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libserializer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libxml</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libswing</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-rtf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/itext-rtf-2.1.7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.3-GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core-3.8.3-GA.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.3-GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions-3.8.3-GA.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cewolf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cewolf</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cewolf-0.12.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.20</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cewolf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cewolf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>20030413.023708</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple-1.1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.cmis.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-opencmis-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ar.org.defensoria</groupId>
        <artifactId>gendoc-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please past the pom file into the question...cause many people don't have access onto things like this..

Comment: Struts dojo plugin is deprecated and removed in 2.5.